# Why did I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const`

Tags: javascript

I have created an empty `div` with the id of `warning_messages` and storing that div inside a `const` using javascript but it is throwing an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const`

Here is the div code:

```
<div id="warning_messages"></div>
```

and the javascript:

```
const warningMessages = document.getElementById('warning_messages');
```

Using `var` instead of `const` also throws the same error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Her is my complete JS:

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//Handle Account Status
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    console.log('Logged in');
  } else {
    console.log('Logged out');
  }
});

//Handle Authentication
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', event => {
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    switch(errorCode) {

      const warningMessages = document.getElementById('warning_messages');
      const warningMessagesContainer = document.createElement('p');
      warningMessagesContainer.setAttribute('id', 'warningMessagesContainer');

      case 'auth/wrong-password':
        const invalidText = document.createTextNode('Invalid Password!');
        break;

      case 'auth/invalid-email':
        const invalidText = document.createTextNode('Invalid Email!');
        break;

      warningMessagesContainer.appendChild(invalidText);
      warningMessages.appendChild(warningMessagesContainer);
}
 });

});
```

Comment: Your browser does not support `const`/es6. Consider using a transpiler.

Comment: A wild guess - your browser doesn't support ES6.

Comment: And you're certain it's running in an environment that supports es2015?

Comment: @Neal I have got the latest version of Google Chrome that supports const because I have been using const like that before and it worked just fine, with the above code, I just don't know why it has stopped working.

Comment: Maybe post your full code @ChinmaySarupria there is probably a problem elsewhere in your code...

Comment: Do you have that script in, say, a `<script>` tag?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Please post the code before/after it. there is an error elsewhere...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No it is in a seperate .js file.

Comment: Are you serving the .js file with the correct mime type? It could be trying to parse the file as something other than JavaScript...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If it tried to parse it as something other than JavaScript, it wouldn't throw a JavaScript error.

Comment: @Neal I have added the complete JS.

Comment: @Juhana. You're assuming it's a JavaScript error. Many browsers put parsing errors in the console.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What browsers parse any other language than JavaScript?

Comment: @Juhana almost every single browser. XML, HTML, CSS, and a few others.

Comment: @Juhana Chrome will show parsing errors in a CSS file, or the HTML file, etc.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" is not a CSS, HTML or XML error.

Comment: Now that is true @Juhana :-)

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria there you go. And now you have an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have anything aside from `case`s inside of a switch statement.

Your error is that you start to use a variable inside of a switch without a case.